# Проблема, появляются отступы между CardView и RelativeLayout в Android <5.0

Tags: java, android

Я использую CardView, внутри которого находится RelativeLayout, на RelativeLayout находится уже моя разметка. Проблема в том, что на версиях андроида меньших 5.0 появляются небольшие отступы или пробелы между CardView и RelativeLayout (тестил версии 4.4 точно), а в Android 5.0 и выше все в порядке и никаких отступов нет. В чем проблема? Как это можно пофиксить?

Код моей разметки:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/Widget.CardContentItem"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_item_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_item_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_item_price"
        style="@style/TextView.PriceTextSearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_item_photo"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:textIsSelectable="false" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_item_category"
        style="@style/TextView.DescriptionText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_item_price"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text_item_price"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_item_price"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:textIsSelectable="false" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout_item_extend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_item_category"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_item_views"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_visibility"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_orange" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_item_views"
            style="@style/TextView.DescriptionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_item_views"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_item_views"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_item_likes"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_item_likes"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/text_item_likes"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_like" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_item_likes"
            style="@style/TextView.DescriptionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить вот это в атрибуты карточки:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```